# Sublime Text 2 / sublimeLinter: only Python is real-time background linted

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I've already spent a few hour on this with not much progress. I'm running Sublime Text 2.0.2 with SublimeLinter v1.7 [1]. It real-time lints Python beautifully, but for many of the other languages I use day-to-day [Javascript, Ruby, CSS/SCSS, etc] it will only display badly-formated warnings via the console when saving[2]. I've tried a number of settings for the executable map. I current have:

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{    
    "javascript": "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "node": "/usr/local/bin/node"
},
```

I've also had just "javascript": "/usr/local/bin/node" in there as well. I've also tried using both jshint and jslint as the "javascript_linter" option.

The console shows SublimeLinter loading and enabling javascript, CSS and Ruby (using node, ruby and node, respectively).

After the enable message on the console I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 431, in _update_view
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 143, in run_once
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/base_linter.py", line 291, in run
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/javascript.py", line 72, in parse_errors
ValueError: Error from jslint: util.puts: Use console.log instead
```

also:

```
SublimeLinter: css enabled (using node.js)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 431, in _update_view
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 143, in run_once
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/base_linter.py", line 291, in run
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/css.py", line 24, in parse_errors
ValueError: Error from csslint: util.puts: Use console.log instead
```

This is followed by raw linting messages such as:

```
[{"id":"(error)","raw":"Use spaces, not tabs.","evidence":"\t\"published\":     
\"#444444\",","line":4,"character":1,"reason":"Use spaces, not tabs."},{"id":"  
(error)","raw":"Expected '{a}' at column {b}, not column 
{c}.","evidence":"\t\"published\":
```

[1] As per https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/512 I rolled back to v1.7 to get PEP8 linting working.

[2] Coffeescript gets real-time linting, which is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this has been fixed in Sublime 3:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/issues/560